# Is there a better front-end than Phplist to integrate with Sendgrid?

Tags: sendgrid, phplist

I'm currently integrating Sendgrid (Back-end API) with Phplist (front-end). However, I realised that there are many features that Phplist doesn't support such as autoresponders, different management levels (sub/superusers) and is unable to send high volumes. May I know if there is a better front end that I can use to integrate it with sendgrid?

Comment: Actually PhpList has different user levels as of version 3.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! [OpenEMM](http://www.openemm.org/) seems to have the features you're looking for. You can see the full list [here](http://www.openemm.org/why/features.html), but the highlights are:

- Configuration of different users with different rights/roles
- Autoresponder mails and error messages (bounce management)

It looks a little tricky to setup, but they have good documentation. Also, [the code is hosted on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openemm/) and the reviews look solid too.

In terms of setting it up with SendGrid, you have to configure your `sendmail` to use our SMTP servers. Luckily, we have a tutorial already that shows you exactly how to do that:

> http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/sendmail/